# Copy attachment from on custom object to another non related custom object

Tags: apex

I need to copy an attachment from a custom object to an unrelated object and then delete the original attachment. My custom object is called PDF_Uploader, when the attachment is created and the invoice number on Invoice__c matches the attachment name, it should copy the attachment to that invoice record. I have started my code and I know that I need to clone the attachment because parentId is non-editable. My  invoiceList is not pulling any results. I may be going about this all wrong. The code is a class that gets called by a trigger. Can someone help with this?

```
    public void copyInvoiceAttachment(){
    List<Invoice__c> invoiceList = new List<Invoice__c>();
    Map<Id,Invoice__c> invoiceMap = new Map<Id,Invoice__c>();
    Set<String>invoiceKeySet = new Set<String>();

    Attachment a;
    for(sObject sObj : Trigger.new){
        a = (Attachment)sObj;
        if(a.ParentId.getSObjectType() == PDF_Uploader__c.getSObjectType()){
             invoiceKeySet.add(a.Name);               
        }
        system.debug(a.Name);
    }

        //2. Query the invoices from the set created above
        invoiceList = [SELECT Id,Invoice_Number__c,Invoice_Attachment_Name_del1__c FROM Invoice__c];
        system.debug(invoiceList.size());

        //3. Loop through the invoices and create map of key
        Map<String,Invoice__c> mapinvoice = new Map<String,Invoice__c>();
        for(Invoice__c i : invoiceList){
            Mapinvoice.put(i.Invoice_Attachment_Name_del1__c,i);
        }
       //4.Loop thorugh attachments and use the map above to cop attachment
        for(sObject sObj : Trigger.new){
            a = (Attachment)sObj; 
            if(Mapinvoice.containsKey(a.Name)){
                //a.ParentId = mapinvoice.get(a.Name).Id;
            }
            system.debug(a.ParentId);
        }       
    }
```

Comment: According to your code: if `invoiceList` is empty then you have no Invoice records. Period. Since there are no filters or limits an empty list means no records. - Any chance you are doing this in a test method?

Comment: The problem is I know there is an invoice that matches. I am not doing this in a test method.

Comment: That matches what exactly? you have no filter in your query to match against. thus no records exist in the system

Comment: The invoice number on the invoice record has to match the attachment name.

Comment: Not according to the code you posted. `invoiceList` which you said was empty has no filters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some generic code that I've pulled out of a deep clone controller we use that may be of some help to you on the cloning part of the problem:

```
private void cloneAttachments(YourType__c oldParent, YourType__c newParent) {

    SObject[] oldChildren = new SObject[] {};
    SObject[] newChildren = new SObject[] {};

    cloneChildren(
            Attachment.SObjectType,
            Attachment.ParentId,
            oldParent.Id,
            newParent.Id,
            oldChildren,
            newChildren
            );

    insert newChildren;
}

private static void cloneChildren(
        SObjectType type,
        SObjectField parentField,
        Id oldParentId,
        Id newParentId,
        SObject[] oldChildren,
        SObject[] newChildren
        ) {
    List<String> fields = new List<String>(type.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
    for (SObject sob : Database.query(''
            + ' select ' + String.join(fields, ',')
            + ' from ' + String.valueOf(type)
            + ' where ' + String.valueOf(parentField) + ' = :oldParentId'
            )) {
        SObject clone = sob.clone();
        clone.put(parentField, newParentId);
        oldChildren.add(sob);
        newChildren.add(clone);     
    }
}
```

The `cloneChildren` method will work with pretty much any type.

Comment: Thank you! We were able to get it to work by stripping the .pdf off the file name.